# PHP How to get a particular JSON values/parameter

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel-5

This is my JSON Response came from an URL API. I use `GuzzleHttp\Client` and `json_decode()` inorder to manage.

```
[{
    "INDEX_ID": "0",
    "NOTES": "0; Farming"
},
{
    "INDEX_ID": "1",
    "NOTES": "Fruit Name; List of Fruits;"
},
{
    "INDEX_ID": "2",
    "NOTES": "Apple"
},
{
    "INDEX_ID": "3",
    "NOTES": "Orange"
},
{
    "INDEX_ID": "4",
    "NOTES": "Grapes"
},
{
    "INDEX_ID": "5",
    "NOTES": "Mango"
},
{
    "INDEX_ID": "6",
    "NOTES": "Animal Name; List of Animal;"
},
{
    "INDEX_ID": "7",
    "NOTES": "Pig"
},
{
    "INDEX_ID": "8",
    "NOTES": "Goat"
},
{
    "INDEX_ID": "9",
    "NOTES": "Cow"
}]
```

But I only need to save list of Fruits in my logfile. Can someone help me how to exclude the other json parameters and get only the particular json parameters using `foreach loop` or any method inorder to get that result.

I just want it to be like this:

```
[
{
    "NOTE_NO." : "001",
    "CATEGORY" : "FRUITS",
    "LISTS_TO_BUY" : [
    {
        "FRUITS": "Apple"
    },
    {
        "FRUITS": "Orange"
    },
    {
        "FRUITS": "Grapes"
    },
    {
        "FRUITS": "Mango"
    }
    ]
 }
 ]
```

He're my codes so far:

```
        $response_body = json_decode($json_response, true);
        $json_new_param = [];

        foreach ($response_body as $value) {
            $json_new_param[] = [
                'FRUITS' => $value['NOTES']
            ];
        }
        $header = [
            [
                'NOTE_NO.' => '001',
                'CATEGORY' => 'FRUITS',
                'LISTS_TO_BUY' => $json_new_param
            ]
        ];
        echo json_encode($header);
```

`$json_response` is the response given above.

Comment: HI, can't you add some filter(s) to your initial request to the API in order to get only fruits or at least items grouped by category or something equivalent? Because in the current state of the response, I don't see any common attribute that can help identifying which intem is a fruit (except its name of course).

Comment: How do you compare for fruits , do you have another set of values that contains only fruits ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to return an array where the key will be the first word from the value using [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) which has this structure: `"NOTES": "Fruit Name; List of Fruits;"`. The key for this would then be "Fruits".

During the array_reduce keep track of the current key using a variable `$currKey`

At the end you could then get the data by using "FRUIT" (Which is the first word) as the array key: `$response_body["FRUIT"]`

```
$response_body = json_decode($json_response, true);
$currKey = "0";

$response_body = array_reduce($response_body, function ($carry, $item) use (&$currKey){
    if (strpos($item['NOTES'], 'Name; List') !== false) {
        $currKey = strtoupper(explode(" ", $item["NOTES"], 2)[0]);
        return $carry;
    }
    $carry[$currKey][] = ["FRUITS" => $item["NOTES"]];
    return $carry;
});

$result = [
    [
        "NOTE_NO" => "001",
        "CATEGORY" => ($name = "FRUITS"),
        "LISTS_TO_BUY" => $response_body["FRUIT"]
    ]
];
echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

That will result in:

```
[
    {
        "NOTE_NO": "001",
        "CATEGORY": "FRUITS",
        "LISTS_TO_BUY": [
            {
                "FRUITS": "Apple"
            },
            {
                "FRUITS": "Orange"
            },
            {
                "FRUITS": "Grapes"
            },
            {
                "FRUITS": "Mango"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/D7Efh)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code .

```
$json_new_param = [];
$fruitFlag = false;
foreach ($response_body as $value) {

    if(strpos($value['NOTES'],'Fruit Name') !== false){
        $fruitFlag = true;
        continue;
    }
    if(strpos($value['NOTES'],'Animal Name') !== false){
        $fruitFlag = false;    
    }

    if($fruitFlag == true){
        $json_new_param[] = [
        'FRUITS' => $value['NOTES']
        ];    
    }

}


echo json_encode($json_new_param, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```